# More than two scripts in a page and stop execution of second when the first false

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I have 5 scripts in my page.I know to keep all five in single script tag but I need it to be deal in separate scripts.My question is that in the first script tag there is a condition if it is true then Ok run the remaining scripts but when in the first script that is in the page top script return false then I want to stop the execution of remaing scripts as well.please help if any one any idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //my code here if true then run the below scripts then stop executing the below script
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//my code here
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//my code here
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//my code here
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//my code here
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var trueorfalse = true;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   if(trueorfalse == true){
      //my code here
   }else{
     //my code here
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save your condition state in `LocalStorage` and check every time before continue.
Like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
   if(yourCondition) {
      localStorage.setItem("runForrestRun", true);
   }
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(localStorage.runForrestRun) {
           // execute your commands
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(localStorage.runForrestRun) {
       // execute your commands
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(localStorage.runForrestRun) {
       // execute your commands
   }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if(localStorage.runForrestRun) {
           // execute your commands
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to enclose the content of each of 4 scripts in 4 different fucntions and then launch that functions from the first script section